# How do I make a custom attribute required field on keycloak registration form

Tags: registration, keycloak

I have the registration process working so that the custom attribute of "phone" is being stored when the user clicks register, if the user typed a phone number in that is. However, I would like it to be a required field and prevent registration from occurring if left blank.  I have not found any keycloak documentation about how to do this.

Comment: Could you show us how you added the custom attribute of 'phone' when the user clicks register.

Comment: @RAbraham : Check here - https://keycloakthemes.com/blog/how-to-add-custom-field-keycloak-registration-page

Answer (score 3):

You have to implement a SPI that [extend the registration form](https://web.archive.org/web/20180327195302/https://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.4/server_development/index.html#modifying-extending-the-registration-form). You can use [standard FormAction](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/3.4.3.Final/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/authentication/forms/RegistrationProfile.java) as base. You will have to add you validation logic to validate() method. For instance:

```
String phoneNumber = formData.getFirst(FIELD_PHONE_NUMBER);
if (Validation.isBlank(phoneNumber) {
  errors.add(new FormMessage(FIELD_PHONE_NUMBER, MISSING_PHONE_NUMBER));
}
```

Comment: formData returns null for formData.getFirst(FIELD_PHONE_NUMBER);

Comment: Would you tell us how to connect keycloak running in a docker container to such an SPI please? It will be useful for someone who is new to keycloak such as me.